# Why are emails ignoring certain CSS when embedding an htm file?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm in the testing phase so for now I have some of my css using the html selectors of certain items and it seems that they are being ignored when I send the email. Also inline stuff like hidden also get ignored. Now I'm sitting her wondering how can I send the email so that I ensure that all of the code will be send and the recipient will have everything displayed correctly?

Comment: check this page to get an idea on what is supported in email clients: https://www.caniemail.com Hint: It's not very much.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem last time. After some research I discovered that certain email providers support different CSS styles.
Therefore, each email provider would support different CSS styles.

Check out [this tool](https://www.caniemail.com/), it allows you to find out what CSS styles certain providers support.

Answer (score -1):

If you use postback or post data to send email, check the url.
You should to check css url and it should start with '/'
ex

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/all.css">
```

Comment: The css is in the htm file I'm not linking any external files.

Comment: Can you insert here a part of your html code with inline CSS

Comment: emails don't allow the linking of CSS files. Most email clients do not even work with inline-style.